# Fluid, flexible and scalable tiles to fill entire width of viewport

Tags: html, css, scale, fluid-layout

I am trying to create fluid and flexible "tiles" for a website, that span across 100% of the viewport of the browser. However, I would like them to scale a bit if needed to eliminate all white space if a the next tile doesn't fit.

A normal div tag with a min-width & min-height of 200px, set to "display: inline-block" gets me most of the way. As I expand the browser window, the boxes will move up to the top line if there is room for another.

My problem is when there isn't room for the next div, there is whitespace on the right. Instead of that, I want each div to 'scale up' to fix the full width of the line.

So if the browser was set to 675px, instead of having 3 divs at 200px, there would be 3 at 225px. But if you then resize the browser to 800px, then there would be 4 divs of 200px.

Sorry if that is hard to understand. Essentially, I am trying to mimic how http://pulse.me displays their articles.

I would like to do this in pure CSS if at all possible, but I suspect for the window resize at least, some javascript will be needed. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you thought about using percentage widths instead of pixels? That way, you give your 800px media query blocks a width of 25%, but your 675px query a width of 33.333333%.

Comment: I thought of percentages, but not the media queries. Wouldn't that mean I need a media query every 200px or so, but the blocks would be the appropriate percentage?

Comment: Yep, you could have as many breakpoints as you want. Take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a pure-CSS approach, you can use media queries combined with percentage widths:

```
.tile {
    /* 4 tiles per row */
    width: 25%;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .tile {
        /* 3 tiles per row */
        width: 33.33333333332%
    }
}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
    .tile {
        /* 2 tiles per row */
        width: 50%
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/bDBMP/1/

Comment: This works. Thanks! Here I was thinking it was an overly complicated task, when a simple thing as percentages is all I needed. I must have been tired. Thanks again!