# Liquid Grid - How do people refer to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I've been playing with the google apps console and it has a fluid page where there are grids of items. When the user makes the window bigger and smaller the width of the grid items gets smaller and smaller until it drops one onto the next row when it cant make each grid item any smaller.

Can anyone tell me what this technique is called so I can find some tutorials. For bonus points, does it require javascript?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique is known as liquid or elastic layout. It is achieved via CSS, no javascript required. If you're looking for tutorials, you might this article useful:

["70+ essential resources for creating liquid and elastic layouts"](http://zomigi.com/blog/essential-resources-for-creating-liquid-and-elastic-layouts/) by Zoe Mickley Gillenwater

Answer (score 1):

Most used method (at least by my observation) is floating div with width in percentage and css media style.
Example

```
.thumb {
    float: left;
    width:18%;
    margin:1%; 
    background: #eee;
    height: 200px;
}

@media (max-width: 724px) {
    .thumb {
        width:48%;
    }
}
```

In example above div.thumb will have width of 20%(margin+width) meaning it will have 5 div per row. And if viewport has width of max 724px there will 2 divs per row.

There are a lot of methods for this but this is most easiest to do, if your div's have same height, otherwise you will have some glitches with float.

EDIT: here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/P2URP/

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for it's called fluid (or scalable, liquid, etc.) "tiles" better than "grid"

This other question may solve yours if you want to do it only with CSS: [Fluid, flexible and scalable tiles to fill entire width of viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595150/fluid-flexible-and-scalable-tiles-to-fill-entire-width-of-viewport)